# Passing Parameters to template While Launching using Dataflow API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have to Pass Parameters to Template While launching Using Dataflow API's in **App Engine Dataflow Job.**

```
 com.google.api.services.dataflow.Dataflow.Projects.Locations.Templates.Launch request1 = 


    dataflowService.projects().locations().templates().launch(projectId,"us-central1",null);

                request1.setGcsPath(template);
                request1.setLocation("us-central1");
                request1.setValidateOnly(false);

                //Storing launch Response
                LaunchTemplateResponse response1 = request1.execute();
```

In My Code, I am Able to Set GCS path, Location, and Validity but not able to set Parameters Like in Cloud Function. is Thier any method to Set Parameters Using java. Because in Python its Possible So I thought So in Java.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'set Parameters like in Cloud Function'? You should be able to set all the parameters for your template just like gcs path etc.

Comment: Ignore the above question, I think I know what you are asking for. Just looked up the API.

Answer (score 1):

To Pass A parameter I Used -:
LaunchTemplateParameters parameters = new LaunchTemplateParameters();

```
LaunchTemplateParameters parameters = new LaunchTemplateParameters();
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put("inputFile", "gs://xyz-bucket/Temp.txt");
parameters.setParameters(map);
        com.google.api.services.dataflow.Dataflow.Projects.Locations.Templates.Launch request1 = 
                        dataflowService.projects().locations().templates().launch(projectId,"us-central1",parameters);

            request1.setGcsPath(template);
            request1.setLocation("us-central1");
            request1.setValidateOnly(false);


            LaunchTemplateResponse response1 = request1.execute();
```